# How do I negate isin method in spark scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

```
val data= List("z", "f", "h")

sqlContext.sql("select name from table")
          .when($"name".isin(data:_*),1)
          .otherwise(0)
          .show
```

How do I do the opposite of `isin`? Do we have anything like `isnotin`?

Comment: I think what you're looking for is `~...isin`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

What you're looking for is either `!` method

```
!($"name".isin(data:_*))
```

or `not` function:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

not($"name".isin(data:_*))
```